# Command to stream MPEG-1 video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

I'm trying to stream MPEG-1 video over FFMPEG with

```
ffmpeg -i "out.ts" -f flv -listen 1 -i rtmp://localhost:8889/live/app -c copy -f flv -listen 1 rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app
```

The *out.ts* file is a MPEG-1 video encoded with

```
ffmpeg -i out.avi -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -b:v 1500k -r 30 -bf 0 -codec:a mp2 -b 0 -q 5 -t 1 out.ts
```

When I try to open the stream with [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html): `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app` media is not playing. What's the command to stream MPEG-1 video over FFMPEG?

Comment: Why MPEG-1 video? So old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stream MPEG-1 video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i out.ts -an -f rtp_mpegts rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Credit to: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-October/028879.html

*(Although the source video is 720p, the stream in VLC looks like 360p and no audio is streamed, any idea would be appreciated)*

Answer (score 2):

RTMP does not have support for mpeg1 video or mpeg2 audio. You can see the complete list if supported code in the fly specification under the VIDEODATA header.

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Comment: What protocol can I use to stream MPEG-1 video using FFMPEG that I can play in VLC?

Comment: TS over UDP, RTP, maybe SRT.